# Unexpected result when using PlotRange in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, version-10, graphics

```
 Show[
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

gives the expected result in *Mathematica* 9

[image: image with correct plot range]

but in *Mathematica* 10.0.1 the plot range is larger than wanted:

[image: image with too large plot range]

Is this a bug?

With

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

one gets the with *Mathematica* 10 the same output as with *Mathematica* 9.

Comment: Nope, if `PlotRange` is different then line range is different, but it is not the case. What is then?, the algorithm behind `PlotRangePadding` probably, use `PlotRangePadding -> 0` to fix that.

Comment: `PlotRangePadding->None` also works. This is probably no bug, unless the changed behavior of `Framed->True` was unintentional (who knows). BTW, why not put all options into the `Plot` call?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about PlotRangePadding.

Comment: @YvesKlett: If I use PlotRange inside Plot I do not get the unwanted padding. Only with Show I get this (by me) unexpected behavior.

Comment: Plot styling was redone in V10 with plot "themes."  There have been several changes in the default behavior.  No doubt an industrious person could track down all the differences. :)

Comment: Not a bug, just a side effect of an intentional change.

Comment: Why is this on hold? Where else than in this forum should I ask such a question? It was not a "simple mistake". I executed the same code in Mathematica 9 and 10 and got different outputs.

Comment: Using `Show` introduces an incorrect `PlotRangePadding`. I don't think it's "an intentional change". If it's not a bug, than at least it's an unexpectable misbehavior. See my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69534/18476) to another question and compare `AbsoluteOptions[
 Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1], PlotRangePadding]` with `AbsoluteOptions[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], PlotRangePadding]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments to this question answer it fully, but I think we should get a answer on record rather than closing the question as a "simple error" or "easily found in documentation" as neither applies.

> Plot styling was [modified] in V10 with plot themes [and in other ways]. There have been several changes in the default behavior. [This is not] a bug, just a side effect of an intentional change.

The `PlotRangePadding` option can be used to restore the V9 behavior.

```
PlotRangePadding -> 0
```

or

```
PlotRangePadding -> None
```

will work.

Comment: To be more specific: The plot range padding of Show[...] has changed in Mathematica 10. Plot[..] seems to be unchanged in this respect.