# SmoothHistogram inside Show doesn't respect plot range clipping?

Tags: plotting, bugs

You can try this for yourself. Run the following code a couple of times:

```
Show[
 Plot[PDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Filling -> Bottom, PlotStyle -> Red],
 SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], 500], 
  Filling -> Bottom],
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}]
```

Eventually you'll find a misbehaved plot where the smooth histogram is completely out of the graphics bounds, even interfering with other cells of the notebook (you might have to execute the above code a couple of times to see this effect, due to the randomness of the data).

If I export the graphic to pdf, the same issue is visible in the pdf (when I export a grid of these plots, the smooth histograms from one row interfere with the row above).

For example:

```
 GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[Show[
Plot[PDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Bottom, PlotStyle -> Red],
SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], 500], 
 Filling -> Bottom],
PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}], {i,
 1, 25}], 5]]
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

Why does this happen? Is this a bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: This issue is not limited to `SmoothHistogram` and also isn't caused by an incorrect `PlotRangeClipping`, but is the result of a wrong `PlotRangePadding` added by `Show`.

Comment: It's version 10.4 and I'm still getting the same behavior. I filed a bug report.

Answer (score 11):

## The quick workaround:

You have to add the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0` (or its equivalent `PlotRangePadding -> None`) to `Show`.

```
Show[SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], 500], Filling -> Bottom], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}]
```

> [image: plot1]

```
Show[SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], 500], Filling -> Bottom], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

> [image: plot2]

---

## The reason and its solution

The reason for this issue is a misbehavior of `Show` (or probably it's a bug), when it is used with a `PlotRange` option. This is independent of `SmoothHistogram`. It shows up, whenever the `PlotRange` specified in `Show` is smaller than the range in the original plot.

Simplifying the example:

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/2], 500];

Show[SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}]
```

> [image: plot3]

shows an incorrect `PlotRange`.
One would expect the same output as from

```
SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}]
```

> [image: plot4]

Using the "quick workaround"

```
Show[SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

> [image: plot5]

one can still see a small overlap over the vertical axis.

Before we get to the final solution, let's check what the difference between using `PlotRange` within the original plot and within `Show` is.

```
AbsoluteOptions[
  SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}],  
  PlotRangePadding]
```

> ```
> {PlotRangePadding -> {{0., 0.}, {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}}
> ```

```
AbsoluteOptions[
  Show[SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}], 
  PlotRangePadding]
```

> ```
> {PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}}
> ```

Therefore one has to use the option `PlotRangePadding -> {{0., 0.}, {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}` in `Show`, in order to force `Show` to behave in the expected way when a `PlotRange` smaller than the range in the original plot is specified within `Show`.

```
Show[
  SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0., 0.}, {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

> [image: plot6]

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to use `RegionFunction`.

Just to revisit this question, I've found that Karsen 7.'s solution is not always working for me (at least on version 9).  Suppose we want to show both a `Histogram` and a `SmoothHistogram`.  So we try:

```
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom]]
```

And we get the problem as expected.

[image: 1]

Now we try the `PlotRangePadding` trick:

```
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

and it doesn't help:

[image: 2]

However, using a `RegionFunction` on the `SmoothHistogram`:

```
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Bottom,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 <= x <= 10]]]
```

[image: 3]